# Python print() throws an invalid handle after call into dll

Tags: python, exception, dll, ctypes

Using ctypes to import a DLL. Occasionally, after a function from the dll is called and I call the print() function in Python, I get an OS Error: Invalid handle.

The calls to the dll are successful and 90% of the time the application works without a hitch. Every 10 runs this exception will throw and I can't even catch it properly since I don't have a way to restore the handle.

I'm think the dll is somehow messing with the stdout handle that print() uses. There are some functions within the dll that still print to stdout. Is there any way to reacquire a valid handle?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "{PATH}/demo.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(" ")
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

Comment: Could try saving them: `sys_stdout = sys.stdout`,  `sys_stderr = sys.stderr` before, then afterwards restore them  `sys.stdout = sys_stdout`,  `sys.stderr = sys_stderr`.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas Sorry, it's added now

Comment: I don't use Windows so I can't even try to test problem. Maybe DLL close handler to `stdout` or it assing different handler and this makes problem. I would first check what is assigned to `sys.stdout` - because `print()` doesn't works so it may need to send information to some file and later check this file in text editor.

Comment: What's `sys.stdout.fileno()` returning (before and after)? Same for *sys.stderr*.

Comment: ```sys.stdout.fileno()``` returns 1 before and after call to dll. ```sys.stderr.fileno()``` returns 2. @CristiFati

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been fixed by duplicating the stdout handle using `os.dup2()`

```
# Duplicate stdout
stdout_copy = 0
os.dup2(sys.stdout.fileno(), stdout_copy)

# Restore stdout
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(stdout_copy,"w")
```